# Oracle 11g connectivity over windows based client-server net

Tags: oracle-11g, windows

I have two PCs as follows: I want to create network for both PCs and share Oracle database from PC1

1. PC1 (windows 10 Pro 64-bit operation system) - Oracle 11g Installed
2. PC2 (windows 10 Pro 64-bit operation system)

I need SQL Developer connectivity and application connectivity. The application is developed with vb.net 2015. Is this possible?

If yes then please tell me how. Tried many things but not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that these machines are sitting in the same network domain, have no firewalls between them and that you're running with everything "as standard", then you *should* be able to access the Database Instance running on PC1 from PC2 using *these* parameters in SQL Developer:

```
Connection Type: Basic
Hostname:        PC1
Port:            1521 
SID:             SID of database instance (ORACLE_SID from PC1)
```

For connecting your Application, check out https://www.connectionstrings.com/

If you're getting Oracle (ORA-?????) errors, add them into the question so we can [try to] diagnose the problem.

Comment: i have only 2 pcs , both have windows 10 , can i make network domain with those two pcs ???